# How do i make jquery display text and this function together?

Tags: jquery, variables, text

I learned how to display text + variable, but in this case i can't figure out what to do, i tried a lot of variations with commas, but i feel that my lack of basic knowledges plays crucial role here, help please

```
$('div:Contains('"Some text" + '+ $.trim(this.value) +'')')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SO formatting is showing you that your function call is being interpreted as a string literal.  Rather than

```
$('div:Contains('"Some text" + '+ $.trim(this.value) +'')')
```

try

```
$('div:Contains("Some text"' + $.trim(this.value) +')')
```

Also, what is your goal?

Comment: shouldn't it be `$('div:Contains(' + 'Some text' + $.trim(this.value) +')')` with the plus after the first paranthesis as well?

Comment: Your suggested modification can be simplified to exclude that '+' altogether `$('div:Contains(' + 'Some text' + $.trim(this.value) +')')`.  I did edit my post to include his quotation marks in the first string literal, thank you for pointing that out